# debug crash of tesseract lib in C# application

Tags: c#, tesseract

I build an dotNet Core 3.1 application running as windows service. I integrated the tesseract C lib for OCR. The service should run 24/7 an it is doing ocr nearly nonstop. works fine on my machine :-). on customer site it crashes ~1 a day. I know it crashes somewhere in the lib, not in the c# part. I am looking for tools, ideas on how to debug the native c lib in my application. Or get some more information, what went wrong. There is not someting like a stacktrace in C which i can give my C# logger?
Thanks!

Comment: _I know it crashes somewhere in the lib, not in the c# part_: How did you determine this? Have you used [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)s in your code to ensure that anything that has a `Dispose` method is disposed of?

Comment: I have the same issue with tesseract lib, there's only one "using" that's available ( using (var ocrInput = new OcrInput())" and I'm using it. Still crashes randomly with no debug stopping, program just stops.